# Connect two machines through an intermediary machine

Tags: ssh, java, routing

I am dealing with 3 machines: X (where my database is) , Y , Z ( where my java application is). X has a route to Y and Z , Z has no route to X but has a route to Y , Y has no route to X but has a route to Z.

So I establish a tunnel from Z to X , by first forwarding a port from X to Z by doing:

```
ssh -t -R 3306:127.0.0.1:4444 name2@domain-of-Y ssh -t -R 4444:127.0.0.1:4444 name3@domain-of-Z
```

and everything seems to go well. However when I try to connect from Z to X, I do:

```
SSH name1@IP-of-X
```

and it prompts to enter the password, and I enter it, but it does not accept the password. I am 100 % sure that it is my correct password because X is my personal machine. The end purpose of the tunnel is to have my java application in Z connect to my database on X. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Routes are bi-directional. so hat do you mean by X has a route to Z/Z has no route to X, and Xhas a route to Y/Y has no route to X????

Comment: @MariusMatutiae route as in I can ssh directly from X to Z. What is the proper word for this? I thought route means forwarding a connection or traffic.

Comment: You seem to be saying you do not have an SSH server running on X. Is this correct? If so, your problem is solved by simply installing the ssh server on X, which you will then be able to reach from any pc on your LAN, not just X and Z.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae No I actually did start the ssh server on machine X by running sudo service sshd start

Comment: I am trying to SSH from Z to X that is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I need to do this so I can connect from my program on machine Z to my database on machine X

Comment: You have an authentication problem, then. Restart your sshd server on X with sudo service ssh stop; sudo /usr/bin/sshd -Dd. On Z, start the ssh client with ssh me@X -vvv and post the output from both server and client here.

Comment: In this folder you mention I do not have that binary file. This what I get when I do : ls /usr/bin/ss*

Comment: /usr/bin/sscape_ctl  /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id  /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
/usr/bin/ssh         /usr/bin/ssh-keygen   /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy
/usr/bin/ssh-add     /usr/bin/ssh-keyscan
/usr/bin/ssh-agent   /usr/bin/ssltap

Comment: Sorry, my bad: it should have been /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd

Comment: when I do what you told me on X this is what I get:                               debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 3 ECDSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-Dd'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.

Comment: On Z when I try to ssh, this is what I write: ssh name_of_X@127.0.0.1 and this is what I get: Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: I used the IP of the loop over network to set up the initial tunnel.

Comment: You should use the IP of server X, plus you should add the output to your initial post.

Comment: I changed the IPs in the original command to the local IPs in X and Y: `ssh -t -R 3306:IP-of-X:4444 name2@domain-of-Y ssh -t -R 4444:IP-of-Y4444 name3@domain-of-Z`

Comment: However now when I try to connect from Z to X, I am not prompted for a password this what I do:                                              ssh -t -p 3306 name-of-X@IP-of-X